# Concatenate Python lists of different lengths by ID

Tags: python-3.x, list, string-concatenation

I have a script that finds substrings in a list, but in the last loop it does not concatenate the strings correctly.
Correct result:

```
IDS00388680 Block Commands
IDS00389632 empty
IDS00389629 Run queue offset
IDS00389628 empty
```

Script result:

```
['IDS00388680', 'Verification error', 'Block Commands']
['IDS00389632', 'Run queue offset', 'Team LS']
['IDS00389629', 'empty', 'empty']
['IDS00389628', 'empty', 'empty']
```

Error in the "Step3" loop.
I need to combine the results "data", "result_cycle" by number IDS***
Any ideas on how to fix this error?

My Script:

```html
from itertools import zip_longest

task_list = [('IDS00388680', 'https://jira.domain/browse/30682\r\n\r\nA call to the block command has been registered: IDS0147121164\r\nerror: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] will be decided in circulation.')
,('IDS00389632', 'https://jira.domain/browse/30752\r\n\r\nOne-time failure, probably due to the procedure freezing for a second, the problem was fixed by restarting.\r\n incident resolved')
,('IDS00389629', 'https://jira.domain/browse/30753\r\n\r\nThe package did not have time to finish work due to launch at the end of the day.\r\nReconfigured the cluster\r\n incident resolved')
,('IDS00389628', 'https://jira.domain/browse/30754\r\n\r\nReduced resources as a result, there were not enough threads to execute.\r\n incident resolved')]

result_cycle = [['IDS00388680', 'Verification error', 'Block Commands'],
                ['IDS00389629', 'Run queue offset', 'Team LS']]
result = []

#Step3 - concatenate the IDS field in the task_list and the values ​​from the result_cycle
ziplong = zip_longest(task_list, result_cycle, fillvalue='empty')
for i in ziplong:
    if i[1] != "empty":
        result.append([i[0][0], i[1][1], i[1][2]])
    else:
        result.append([i[0][0], "empty", "empty"])

for m in result:
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are appending a list of strings to the list.
Try

```
result.append(' '.join([i[0][0], i[1][1], i[1][2]]))
```

This creates a space-joined string and appends it to your list.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem

for i in ziplong:
    if i[1] != "empty":
        result.append(' '.join([i[0][0], i[1][1], i[1][2]]))
    else:
        result.append(' '.join([i[0][0], "empty", "empty"]))

Comment: Do you want only 2 columns? In that case remove the index that you don't need.